# result of group_by mysql more than 1 same data

Tags: php, mysql

I use function group_by in mysql, but in big data 116000 record when I run this sintax there is more than 1 same data. What should I do ??

```
SELECT fiedl1, field2, field3
 FROM table
GROUP BY field2
ORDER BY 'field2' ASC

field1|field2|field3
1     |you   |a
2     |you   |b
3     |you   |c
4     |you    |d
5 ...etc
```

result

```
field1|field2|field3
1     |you   |a
2     |you   |b
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  (1) It has no `FROM` clause.  (2) It has columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY` clause.  (3) It is ordering by a constant string.

Comment: after i edited syntax, The results nothing has changed

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It turns out that distinguish "you" and " you" is that there is a space at the beginning of the word "you" other.. thanks for answer ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use group by on all fields, or agregate functions, for example

SELECT fiedl1, field2, field3
  FROM table
  GROUP BY fiedl1, field2, field3
  ORDER BY field2 ASC

OR

SELECT sum(fiedl1), field2, avg(field3)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY field2
  ORDER BY field2 ASC

Comment: It turns out that distinguish "you" and " you" is that there is a space at the beginning of the word "you" other.. thanks for answer :)